# Creating install script form custom web app

Tags: php, installation

I'm looking for option to make **install.php** where user puts all needed data e.g. db host, db username, db pwd etc. Script must put it to php class called config.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->site_address = '';
    $this->db_prefix = '';
    $this->site_desc = '';
    $this->site_title = '';
    $this->hash = '';
    $this->sidebar = false;
    $this->db_host = '';
    $this->db_name = '';
    $this->db_pass = '';
    $this->db_user = '';
    $this->db_port = 3306;
    $this->folder = NULL;
    $this->mailserver = '';
    $this->mailport = '';
    $this->mailuser = '';
    $this->mailpassword ='';

}
```

How to put data from form on **install.php** page to this class constructor?
I was thinking about getting content->find `$this->db_host =` and replace `''` for `'.$_POST['db_host'].'` from form and then put content to file and save, but I don't know how exactly do that. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add variable to your `__construct()`

```
public function __construct($site_address='',$db_prefix='',$site_desc='',$site_title='',$hash='',$sidebar=false){
    $this->site_address = $site_address;
    $this->db_prefix = $db_prefix;
    $this->site_desc = $site_desc;
    $this->site_title = $site_title;
    $this->hash = $hash;
    $this->sidebar = $sidebar;

    // And so on 

}
```

Then from your form you do a `new yourAwesomeClassName('http://hello','$_POST['db_prefix']',...)`

Don't forget few things:

- Never trust user input
- Sanitize/check all your data/inputed format before using them
- Don't save passwords in plain text, at least hash them, better would be using a salt in addition to that of course.

## Update according to comment

(The following may not be a good practice but I'm open to suggestions as this is part of [my current work](https://github.com/funilrys/funombi))

If you need to save your data I suggest you to have a generic file for example ...

### Generic file

[Source](https://github.com/funilrys/funombi/blob/1e5c8f7f53f7d4b980f98b12b3541953fa27e255/App/Config/Database.php)

```
class Database
{

    /**
     * Database host
     * @var string Default: 'your-database-host'
     */
    const DB_HOST = 'your-database-host';

    /**
     * Database name
     * @var string Default: 'your-database-name'
     */
    const DB_NAME = 'your-database-name';

    // And so on

}
```

Then you need a function that writes your data

### Write default data

[Source](https://github.com/funilrys/funombi/blob/0ae2ceffdf32ef5d6c730adb77a9e97fba261ae5/Core/Files.php#L260)

```
public static function writeDatabaseConfig($data)
    {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $root = static::getRoot();
            $databaseFile = $root . 'App' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Config' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Database.php';
            $currentFile = file_get_contents($databaseFile);
            if (strpos($currentFile, 'your') !== false) {
                $oldToNew = array(
                    'host' => 'your-database-host',
                    'name' => 'your-database-name',
                );
                foreach ($oldToNew as $key => $value) {
                    if (isset($data[$key])) {
                        $currentFile = str_replace($value, $data[$key], $currentFile);
                    }
                }
                if (file_put_contents($databaseFile, $currentFile)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

At the end in your `__construct()` you only need to call `writeDatabaseConfig()` to write your data. Once done you can get your information by calling `ConfigClass::DB_HOST` for example ...

Comment: yes, but it will be temporary... It will only be usable when install script runs. I need some idea how to change  empty variable to for example string from install form that will stay in config forever (untill someone will change it). I can be some option of generating new file called config.php during install in specified folder....

Comment: Another thing to add: Don't save passwords in plain text, at least hash them, better would be using a salt in addition to that of course.

Comment: Yes I know that, it's not my problem. I don't know how to generate file config.php via install.php and save all data from from in install.php to use forever from config.php

Comment: @pusty Updated my answer